# if en apertura de tag y cierre - Vue

Tags: vue.js

Trabajando con Vue me he encontrado con un problema.

Quiero mostrar un listado de materiales en un swiper dinámicamente.

Mi problema viene al no poder hacer un if alrededor del div que contiene la clase swiper-slide ni su cierre.

Actualmente mi código es el siguiente:

```
    <div class="material-list swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <template v-for="(material, index) in materials">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="material">
                                <p>{{material.title}}</p>
                                <p>{{material.year}}</p>
                                <p>{{material.category}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </div>
```

y querria conseguir algo asi:

```
    <div class="material-list swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <template v-for="(material, index) in materials">
                       {{ if index == 0 }}
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                        {{/if}}
                            <div class="material">
                                <p>{{material.title}}</p>
                                <p>{{material.year}}</p>
                                <p>{{material.category}}</p>
                            </div>
                        {{ if index == 5 }}
                        </div>
                        {{/if}}
                    </template>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: la sintaxis del if esta mal usada, para hacer un if debes usar la directiva v-if, Pero por lo que veo lo que necesitas es verificar si usar un tag, aunque podría ser una clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario realizar equiquetas de apertura y de cierre en vue, lo que necesitas es realizar es iterar sobre el div con class `.material`. Por tanto tendrias que hacer algo como lo siguiente.

```
 <div class="material-list swiper-container">
   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="material"
          v-for="(material, index) in materials"
          v-key="index">
          <p>{{material.title}}</p>
          <p>{{material.year}}</p>
          <p>{{material.category}}</p>
        </div>               
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

De esta manera creas todos los materiales dentro de tu contenedor `.swiper-slide`

Comment: El problema de eso, es que quiero tener varios swiper-slides con un tope de 10 materials por ejemplo.

Perdón por no haberme expresado correctamente.

Comment: Puedes agregarle un v-for al `.swiper-wrapper` y tener una estructura de objetos algo asi `[[material1, material2], [...], [..]]`cada uno con `x` materiales